# How to package Django Application including all Requirements for Windows

Tags: python, django, installation, bundle, portability

I have developed a Django application which I want to send to the customer. The customer wants to a) store the application on an external USB storage device and b) can be assumed to be not capable of installing a Python and Django stack.

So far I tried [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/DjangoApplication), which has problems with django's templatetags and py2exe, which doesn't even find my `settings.py`. All helpful documents or tutorials I can find are outdated i.e., work with django < 1.5.

What other options are there? I am even trying [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com) now, though so far with little success. I really would appreciate, if anybody could explain one way to do this or point me to a recent tutorial.

---

Since some people asked: The situation is, that the customers want to use the django app (which is a simple database application) on different computers. However, I currently cannot setup a server infrastructure in their office, so the Idea is that I provide them some directory/exe file that they can put on a USB storage device. Whenever somebody wants to use the app, he/she simply connects that device and can start working.

Of course this is not a nice solution and I will set up something better someday, but right now I am looking for a way to package the application as is.

Comment: What are they hoping to do with the application? Obviously, a Django app usually runs on the server rather than the client. Why can't you install it on a server for them?

Comment: I think it would be better and easier to use a virtualenv and then everything will be easily packaged and portable

Comment: @DanielRoseman: See my edit in the question. yuvi: virtualenv requires Python to be installed which I cannot assume.